# Volume of a tetrahedron bounded by planes

Tags: geometry

I need to find the volume of a tetrahedron that's bounded by $4$ planes:

$x = 0$,

$z = 0$,

$14x - 14y + 16z + 9 = 0$,

and

$14y - 8z - 121 = 0.$

I tried plotting this in GeoGebra, but I found it really hard to see the tetrahedron there.

Answer (score 2):

Any three of the four given planes have a point of intersection, which is a vertex of the tetrahedron $T$. Find the four vertices, and compute ${\rm vol}(T)$ via a triple vector product, multiplied by  ${1\over6}$.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate over a triangular base in the $yz$-plane, 
the solid bounded by the planes $x=0$ and $14x - 14y + 16z + 9 = 0$.
The volume of the tetrahedron is given by
$$\int_{z=0}^{14}\int_{y=\frac{16z+9}{14}}^{\frac{8z+121}{14}}\int_{x=0}^{\frac{14y-16z-9}{14}}1\,dxdydz=\frac{448}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_k,y_k,z_k)$ $k=0,1,2,3$, be the vertices of the tetrahedron, obtained by solving 4 systems of equations, each of these systems being obtained by suppressing one of the four equations. Let

$$M=\begin{pmatrix} x_0 & y_0 & z_0 & 1\\ x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & 1\\ x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & 1\\ x_3 & y_3 & z_3 & 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 8 & 121/
    14& 0& 1\\0 & 233/14 & 14 & 1\\0 & 121/14 & 0 & 1\\0 & 9/14 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

It is known (http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath664/kmath664.htm) that the volume of such a tetrahedron is given by formula:

$$\dfrac{1}{3!} det(M)=-448/3$$

which is the same as the result given by @Robert Z (the minus sign is unimportant)